# Background image not moving vertically using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
h1{
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
}
body{
    background-image:url(macOS_wallpaper.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 50%;
}
```

I have an image that I want to use. It is positioned how I want it horizontally, but it is not moving vertically at all (I want to move the image down). I have tried using px and % to move the image, but it won't budge.

How can I adjust the y-component in order for me to move my image down?

Comment: What means 'move down'? Any example, Image?

Comment: Are you looking for padding?

Comment: @AllDani isn't padding in regards to text, not background images?

Comment: @dhaneku.b everything

Comment: @AllDani I don't think padding is the issue here. I just wanted to be able to move my background image around, and adding that line : fixed did that (although it seems like it still have some limitations)

Comment: Not an issue, but a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```html
.class { 
    background-image: url('something.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 0% 50%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-attachment: fixed;` to the body style.